# DevOps YAML Pipeline and variables

Tags: powershell, variables, azure-devops, yaml

I'm a bit of a beginner with YAMl and PS, so bear with me a bit.

The scenario:

I have SQL in Source Control using Redgate SoC and a build pipeline that contains the Redgate Build Extension, I have a task that checks whether there were any changes to Functions, SP's, Tables etc and a condition in the Redgate Build task that will skip the task if there were no changes to the above folders, when there are only scripts(data changes) that were pushed, and all of this works great.  My next challenge (deployment pipeline) was to check if there was a Redgate Build performed to skip the deployment of the Redgate Deployment task.

My thinking here was, create a variable that I can save in the build pipeline and then use in the deployment pipeline (using the Variable Tools extension), under run this task (in the Redgate Deploy Pipeline section, set it to Custom Conditions and then check if the variable is true or not.

Following is my YAML Build pipeline:

```
trigger:
  - dev

variables:
  FunctionsFlag: $false
  ProceduresFlag: $false
  TablesFlag: $false
  DataFlag: $false
  ViewsFlag: $false
  RGDeployFlag: $false

jobs:
  - job: AdventureWorks
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    pool: Enterprise
    cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        clean: true

      - powershell: |
          ## get the changed files
          $files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
          $temp=$files -split ' '
          $count=$temp.Length
          echo "Total changed $count files"
            For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
              {
              $name=$temp[$i]
              echo "this is $name file"
              if ($name -like 'Functions/*')
              {
              ##set the flag variable FunctionsFlagFlag to true
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FunctionsFlag]$True"
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RGDeployFlag]$True"
              ##Set-Variable -Name $(RGDeployFlag) -Value $True
              echo "The answer is $(RGDeployFlag)"
              }
              if ($name -like 'Procedures/*')
              {
              ##set the flag variable StoredProceduresFlagFlag to true
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ProceduresFlag]$True"
              }
              if ($name -like 'Tables/*')
              {
              ##set the flag variable TablesFlagFlag to true
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TablesFlag]$True"
              }
              if ($name -like 'Data/*')
              {
              ##set the flag variable StoredProceduresFlagFlag to true
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DataFlag]$True"
              }
              if ($name -like 'Views/*')
              {
              ##set the flag variable TablesFlagFlag to true
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ViewsFlag]$True"
              }
              if (($name -like 'Functions/*') -or ($name -like 'Procedures/*') -or ($name -like 'Tables/*') -or ($name -like 'Data/*') -or($name -like 'Views/*'))
              {
              ##set the flag variable RGDeployFlag to true
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RGDeployFlag;isoutput=true]$True"
              $RGDeployFlag=$True
              echo "The answer is $(RGDeployFlag)"
              }
              
            echo "The answer is $(RGDeployFlag)"
            }
  
      - task: RedgateSqlChangeAutomationBuild@4
        inputs:
          operation: Build
          dbFolder: RootFolder
          packageName: AdventureWorks
          tempServerTypeBuild: localDB
          buildAdvanced: true
          compareOptionsBuild: 'NoTransactions, IgnoreFileGroups'
          dataCompareOptionsBuild: 'DisableAndReenableDMLTriggers, SkipFkChecks'
          transactionIsolationLevelBuild: readCommitted
          queryBatchTimeoutBuild: '0'
          excludeEnviromentVariables: 'AGENT_*;BUILD_*;SYSTEM_*'
          nugetPackageVersionSelector: Specific
          nugetPackageVersion: '1.0'
          nugetPackageVersionUseBuildId: true
          requiredVersionOfDlma: latestInstalled
        condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables.FunctionsFlag, true),eq(variables.ProceduresFlag, true),eq(variables.TablesFlag, true),eq(variables.DataFlag, true),eq(variables.ViewsFlag, true)))
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Scripts'
          Contents: '**'
          TargetFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/Scripts'
          CleanTargetFolder: true
          OverWrite: true
          preserveTimestamp: true
      - task: variabledehydration@0
        inputs:
          prefixes: 'GITVERSION,BUILD,RGDeployFlag'
          outpath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
```

[Release Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpxmW.png)
[Custom Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXjVn.png)
So my main problem is setting the variable to be used in the deployment pipeline.  Here is where I require some guidance:

Am I supposed to create multiple stages and or jobs in order to do this, or is my YAML structure correct, and that I'm just setting the values incorrectly?

Inside the if statements of my PS section, I have been trying a few tests to manipulate the outcome, but so far with little success.

Regardless of how I set the variable, it keeps evaluating to false.

I look forward to your comments.

Regards

Wic

Comment: When I try to set the variable using the set-variable cmdlt, (Set-Variable -Name $(RGDeployFlag) -Value $True), I get an error stating I cannot set a read only variable:  Cannot overwrite variable false because it is read-only or constant.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out why this did not work:

Firstly, I had to remove the variable 'declaration' from the YAML as I was setting it to be cast in stone:

Added an initialization for my variable.

And lastly added the set variable.

Voila, I am able to use that variable in my release pipeline.

The complete YAML pipeline now looks like:

```html
trigger:
  - dev
## Removed the variables section here
jobs:
  - job: AdventureWorks
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    pool: Enterprise
    cancelTimeoutInMinutes: 1
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        clean: true
      - powershell: |
          ## Initialize my variable here
          $RGDeployFlag = $false
          ## get the changed files
          $files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
          $temp=$files -split ' '
          $count=$temp.Length
          echo "Total changed $count files"
            For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
            {
            $name=$temp[$i]
            echo "this is $name file"
            if ($name -like 'Functions/*')
            {
            ##set the flag variable FunctionsFlagFlag to true
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FunctionsFlag]$True"
            }
            if ($name -like 'Procedures/*')
            {
            ##set the flag variable StoredProceduresFlagFlag to true
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ProceduresFlag]$True"
            }
            if ($name -like 'Tables/*')
            {
            ##set the flag variable TablesFlagFlag to true
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TablesFlag]$True"
            }
            if ($name -like 'Data/*')
            {
            ##set the flag variable StoredProceduresFlagFlag to true
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DataFlag]$True"
            }
            if ($name -like 'Views/*')
            {
            ##set the flag variable TablesFlagFlag to true
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ViewsFlag]$True"
            }
            if (($name -like 'Functions/*') -or ($name -like 'Procedures/*') -or ($name -like 'Tables/*') -or ($name -like 'Data/*') -or($name -like 'Views/*'))
            {
            ## set the flag variable RGDeployFlag to true
            $RGDeployFlag = $true
            }
            ## Test to see what the variable value is
            "RGDeployFlag : $RGDeployFlag" 
          }
      - task: RedgateSqlChangeAutomationBuild@4
        inputs:
          operation: Build
          dbFolder: RootFolder
          packageName: AdventureWorks
          tempServerTypeBuild: localDB
          buildAdvanced: true
          compareOptionsBuild: 'NoTransactions, IgnoreFileGroups'
          dataCompareOptionsBuild: 'DisableAndReenableDMLTriggers, SkipFkChecks'
          transactionIsolationLevelBuild: readCommitted
          queryBatchTimeoutBuild: '0'
          excludeEnviromentVariables: 'AGENT_*;BUILD_*;SYSTEM_*'
          nugetPackageVersionSelector: Specific
          nugetPackageVersion: '1.0'
          nugetPackageVersionUseBuildId: true
          requiredVersionOfDlma: latestInstalled
        condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables.FunctionsFlag, true),eq(variables.ProceduresFlag, true),eq(variables.TablesFlag, true),eq(variables.DataFlag, true),eq(variables.ViewsFlag, true)))
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Scripts'
          Contents: '**'
          TargetFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/Scripts'
          CleanTargetFolder: true
          OverWrite: true
          preserveTimestamp: true
      - task: variabledehydration@0
        inputs:
          prefixes: 'GITVERSION,BUILD,RGDeployFlag'
          outpath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
```